# Local DNS server on OS X with no network connection

Tags: macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard, dns

I've got a local DNS server running, with an entry in `etc/resolver/gm.local` to make *.gm.local use this local DNS server (which in turn just points everything to localhost).

This works fine when I have a network connection enabled, but when there is no network (ie. on the train), I'm unable to access these domains via any web browser (although nslookup, curl et al seem to work correctly)

Does anyone know how to get what I assume is the OS X DNS resolution libraries to look up these entries when I'm not on a network conncection?

Comment: Use [fully qualified domain names](http://menandmice.com/online_docs_and_faq/glossary/fqdn.htm) and prove to both us and yourself that you really do have the DNS problem that you think that you have.  [A WWW browser is not a DNS diagnosis tool.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/dns-narrow-problem-locus.html#WebBrowser)

Comment: Also consider using something else than `local.`, which is normally reserved for Avahi/mDNS.

Comment: Using a fully qualified domain name made no difference. The lookup tab in Network Utility, ping and python are all able to resolve the domain name, but firefox, safari and chrome are not. I have no idea what the DNS problem I do have is, but it's clearly something to do with what the browsers are doing that the simpler tools are not - and it is this which is the problem I'm seeking a solution for.